# $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(\theta)\sin(n\theta)d{\theta}=0$, Is the solution correct?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let the integral be,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\!\!\!\!\!\sin\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(n\theta\right)\,{\rm d}\theta&=
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}2\sin\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(n\theta\right)
\,{\rm d\theta}
={1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left\{%
\cos\left(\left[n - 1\right]\theta\right) - \cos\left(\left[n + 1\right]\theta\right)\right\}
\,{\rm d}\theta
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 2}\left\{%
{\sin\left(\left[n - 1\right]\theta\right) \over n - 1}
 -
 {\sin\left(\left[n + 1\right]\theta\right) \over n + 1}\right\}^{\pi}_{0}
\end{align}

Comment: I have edited the same.

Comment: Except for the missing assumption $n\neq \pm 1$, it's correct (assuming $n$ an integer).

Comment: I need to find the integral for n = 1 separately.

Comment: Yes, because it's not $0$ then.

Comment: You might want to look at Fourier Analysis which use this principle to do transforms.

Answer (score 2):

Let me define $I_n$ as your integral. Then, it can be shown that

$$I_n = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}  \sin{(n\pi)}/(1-n^2)& \text{if } n \neq \pm 1 \\ \pm\pi/2 & \text{if } n = \pm 1  \\ \end{array}\right.,$$

and since $\sin{n\pi} = 0$ for every $n \in  \mathbb{Z}$:

$$I_n = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}  0 & \text{if } n \neq \pm 1 \\ \pm\pi/2 & \text{if } n = \pm 1  \\ \end{array}\right..$$

In this last step I have assumed that $n$ is an integer. Omit this if you are considering every real value of $n$.

I hope this may help you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In general for $m,n>0$, $$\int_0^\pi\sin mt\sin ntdt=\frac {\pi}2\delta_{mn}$$

Answer (score 0):

You had
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\cos\bigl((n-1)\theta\bigr)-\cos\bigl((n+1)\theta\bigr)\right)d{\theta}\ .$$
As $\cos$ is an even function this implies
$$I_n=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\cos\bigl((n-1)\theta\bigr)-\cos\bigl((n+1)\theta\bigr)\right)d{\theta}=\cases{\pm{\pi\over2} &$(n=\pm 1)$,\cr 0&(otherwise).\cr}$$